# R multidplyr: how to assign packages to clusters

Tags: r, parallel-processing, dplyr, multicore, multidplyr

I am using the package [multidplyr](https://github.com/hadley/multidplyr) where you can split the data over multiple cores within a dplyr pipe.
You can assign values and functions to the cores with `cluster_assign_value()`, but the question is **how to assign packages to the clusters?** Because it should be able to use packages within the functions.

I expect something like `cluster_assign_package()` but I cannot find such function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also assign a package to the clusters with `cluster_library()`

Comment: That might even be better yes

Answer (score 0):

Already found the answer: add `library(packageName)` in the function definition.